# Specifying Order of Variables for SAS Report

Tags: report, sas, datastep

I am working on a project where I need to specify the order of objects in the data for a custom SAS report. I am having trouble with something that should be easy, here is an example of the data I am working with.

```
obs   ord   ord2  name
  1     3      1    A
  2     3      .    B
  3     3      .    C
  4     3      .    D
  5     4      1    E
  6     4      .    F
  7     5      1    G
  8     5      .    H
  9     5      .    I
 10     5      .    J
```

What I'd like is...

```
    obs   ord   ord2  name
      1     3      1    A
      2     3      2    B
      3     3      3    C
      4     3      4    D
      5     4      1    E
      6     4      2    F
      7     5      1    G
      8     5      2    H
      9     5      3    I
     10     5      4    J
```

So that for every first occurrence of ord, ord2 = 1,...,n_i.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: How about doing this step on the original data? It is relatively easier to manipulate using data step.

Comment: @RobbieLiu that might be even more difficult, unfortunately I need to produce a table that looks like this... http://www.stat.wmich.edu/wang/680/docs/aetest.lst

Comment: If the original data set looks like what you have shown here, the order number can be added using data step. Then you can use ′proc report´ to customize report. Is that right?

Comment: @RobbieLiu here is what the original data looks like... https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-A7YPjHrXqNMjY3TFFsd0lVZkE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @RobbieLiu here is what I have... https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-A7YPjHrXqNR3Z5czBsREhrMDg/view?usp=sharing    this is what I want... https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-A7YPjHrXqNM2xUeEJlQkhNek0/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please do not attach files via google drive.  Include sufficient code in your question _in text_ for it to be answerable.

Comment: @joe I think that my question could have been understood without the images, I only chose to include images in response to the particular questions in the comments. Would you have another suggestion for posting codes and examples in the comments?

Comment: Look at the various other questions on this site.  Post code and examples _as text_, not as images.  If it's not short enough to post as text, it's probably not a good question.  You didn't include your proc report code in the question, which made this a "write code for me" question - which is strongly discouraged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just apply a group numbering to the original data set, provided that the table has been sorted by ord.

```
data table1;
   set table1;
   by ord;
   ord2_ + 1;
   if first.ord then ord2_ = 1;
   drop ord2;
   rename ord2_=ord2;
Run;
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but it didn't seem to work.
here is the code, https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-A7YPjHrXqNSHJUQUhqNzdDQmc/view?usp=sharing here is what it produced... https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-A7YPjHrXqNN3ZBcjFpd3FnaXc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @k6adams I forgot that your table already has `ord2`. So just create a new serial then rename.